# Global scope on CRUD methods

Tags: php, laravel

I have model `Page` with Global Scope `active`:

```
/**
 * The "booting" method of the model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('active', true);
    });
}
```

When page active = 0. I can't get access to edit and change active to 1.
In controller I try call function withoutGlobalScope('active'), but not working. I get 404 error.

```
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Page  $page
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Page $page)
{
    $page->withoutGlobalScope('active');
    return view('admin.pages.edit-add', compact('page'));
}
```

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: which type of exception was thrown?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you'll be receiving a 404 is because of Route model binding. Essentially, the app is trying to resolve the Page model for you before it even gets to the controller method and it'll throw a 404 if it can't find it.

You should be able to get around this problem by adding something like the following to the constructor of controller:

```
Route::bind('page', function ($id) {
    return Page::withoutGlobalScope('active')->find($id) ?? abort(404);
});
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: It is recommended to put such code in the `boot()` method of a service provider such as the `RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: @Namoshek Yes, that would be the case if you wanted this to be applied everywhere in your code, however, in this case it is already applied globally and the OP doesn't want it to be applied for these routes. Alternatively, if the OP is wanting to apply it to more that one controller (but not all of them) I would probably suggest using middleware instead.